# swing and GUI components not appearing

Tags: java, swing

I'm a complete noobie with swing. I'm trying to set a few JPanels and TextAreas to show up but after spending 2 days reading the APIs and trying to add panels to frames and textareas to panels and nothing is showing up.. I'm utterly confused. If anyone could explain how is the best way to do this I would be very grateful

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());                           // J FRAME

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();                                               // first panel on the left
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, 1));
//  frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel surname = new JLabel();
    JLabel initial = new JLabel();
    JLabel ext    = new JLabel();
    surname.setOpaque(true);
    initial.setOpaque(true);
    ext.setOpaque(true);
    frame.add(surname);
    panel.add(initial);
    panel.add(ext);


    JTextArea table = new JTextArea();
    table.setEditable(false);
    panel.add(table);
    table.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding stuff to the JFrame after it's already visible. If you do that, you need to revalidate your JFrame so it knows to redo its layout.

You could also just wait to show your JFrame until after you've added everything.

Edit: Here is an example program that shows what I'm talking about. Try running this, then take out the call to revalidate() to see the difference.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JButton show = new JButton("Show");
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent showE) {
                frame.add(new JLabel("Test"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.revalidate(); //tell the JFrame to redo its layout!
            }

        });

        frame.add(show);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Salah That, uh, agrees with what I said exactly.

Comment: And now @Salah is deleting his comments, guess that means he realized his mistake...

Comment: Yea i was mistaken, but still in the OP case, it will not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an empty elements like:

```
JLabel surname = new JLabel();
```

Your elements is already added but have nothing to be display.

Try :

```
JLabel surname = new JLabel("UserName");
JLabel initial = new JLabel("Iinitial");
JLabel ext = new JLabel("Ext");
JTextArea table = new JTextArea(10, 5);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the text area isn't visible. The correct answer is that the JFrame must be revalidated when you add components to it after it's already visible.

Comment: Containers will automatically re-validate itself when a new component has been added. so you don't need to re-validate it by your self, just try the code before saying and down voting (by the way its not me who downvoted your answer).

Comment: What you are saying is not correct (when it comes to Containers that are already visible, like in OP's case), and the documentation that you yourself posted agrees with me.

Comment: have you tried it, just go and try that code, you'll see that you don't have to call `validate()` method, it we be automatically re-validate itself.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that? You are completely incorrect here, and the fact that you're deleting your comments shows me that you're starting to realize that. StackOverflow is not a place for bickering though, so I'll let the OP decide for himself.

Comment: Yea i was mistaken about your answer, and my deleted comment, but still you didn't addressed the issue here, because even if you called `validate()` method, you will not get anything in this case.

Comment: The JTextArea will become visible if you add a call to revalidate().

Comment: No it will not, because it has a `0` rows and columns !!!!!!!!!!!! your `validate()` will not do anything in this case.